# how to change the 'video::-webkit-media-controls-panel' on run time from the code ?

Tags: html, html5-video

i need to change the attribute of the 'video::-webkit-media-controls-panel' on runtime from the code

In some case i need to set it to be

```
  video::-webkit-media-controls-panel
  {
       display: none !important;
       opacity: 0 !important;
  }
```

and other case i need to set it to be ( if some checkbox on the code is checked )

```
  video::-webkit-media-controls-panel 
  {
         display: flex !important;
         opacity: 1 !important;
  }
```

I can't find a way to change it from the code at run time

how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One hack i could think of is that you can inject/remove the css rule programmatically as shown below.

```js
function injectStyles(rule, id) {
 removeStyle(id);
  var div = $("<div />", {
    html: '<style id="' + id +'">' + rule + '</style>'
  }).appendTo("body");    
}

function removeStyle(id) {
  $('#'+id).remove();
}

$("#change").on("click", function() {
  injectStyles(`video::-webkit-media-controls-panel
  {
       display: none !important;
       opacity: 0 !important;
  }`, 'd');
});

$("#remove").on("click", function() {
  removeStyle('d');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Video Sample Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Sample Page</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <video id='video' controls="controls" preload='none'
        width="600" poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png">
        <source id='mp4' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
        <source id='webm' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type='video/webm'/>
        <source id='ogv' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type='video/ogg'/>
        <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
      </video>
    </div>
  <button id="change">Hide</button>

<button id="remove">Show</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it like Thaadikkaran but without the jquery

```
const injectStyles = function (rule, id) {
  console.log("injectStyles");
  removeStyle(id);
  const style = document.createElement("style");
  style.id = id;
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rule));
  document.head.appendChild(style);
};

const removeStyle = function (id) {
  const el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el) {
    el.remove();
  }
};
```